# How to implement WSDL service in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl

We are working on a website which will provide the client access to a WSDL service via SOAP mechanism.

How do i implement a WSDL service in PHP ?

What is Apache Axis2 and Apache CXF ?
Does it suit my requirements ? Will it work on PHP or do i have to code it in Java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.server.html

I was working with Zend_Soap_Server and it was very simple - just give an object to Zend's autodiscovere black box and it generates WSDL file.

Here more info about other WSDL generators:
http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/php/Creating_A_Web_Service_With_PHP_5's_SOAP_Extension.htm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Axis2

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_CXF